# Azure service bus - Topic full

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I have a process(Process A) that keeps sending events to an ASB topic. There are multiple consumers of the topic and therefore multiple subscriptions. So lets say that one of the consumer's process is down. And due to this the topic gets full as the messages are not consumed. Does this mean then Process A also fails as it is not able to send messages to ASB topic as its full?

Answer (score 1):

Two more things to check:

1. Make sure that your dead letter queue is not full that counts towards the size of the entity.
2. Make sure that you have at least one subscription that works for each message. For example, if you send a message with ID=1, but you only have a subscription with ID=2, the messages will get backed up.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are correct, once the limit is reached the queue stops.

However, with partitioning (using all 16 partitions * 5 GB), you can store up to 80 GB:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/partitioned-service-bus-queues-and-topics/

Another solution is to use auto forwarding, so the topic forwards all messages to another queue/topic
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-auto-forwarding/
This way each subscriber can have it's own queue of 5GB (or 80GB if you use partition)

Some more info:
https://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/documentation/articles/service-bus-azure-and-service-bus-queues-compared-contrasted/
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-quotas/